# How do you embed a form in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, infopath

I would like to have a feedback form embedded on the homepage of my sharepoint 2010 site.  I've created said form using InfoPath and have published the form to the site.  However when I add the form as a webpart on the page it appears as link like it's another document, and you can only complete the form when you click the link.

How can I embed the form on the actual web page?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Have you embedded the infopath form in the SharePoint Infopath webPart ?

http://www.bizsupportonline.net/infopath2010/embed-infopath-form-sharepoint-2010-web-part.htm

Comment: Thanks Madhur, this has solved the problem.  Can't believe I missed this!